# Speed up or optimize persistent drawrect

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-graphics, drawrect

I'm using the following code to create a persistent DrawRect  for a finger painting type exercise

When I run on the simulator it is fine,   when I run on the iPad it gets delayed turning curves in jagged lines  Please can some one help optimize or suggest a better method

Thanks in advance

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
 UIGraphicsPushContext(drawingContext);
 CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(drawingContext); 
 image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];

 if (draw) {
 CGContextSetLineWidth(drawingContext, (2.0 * size) );
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(drawingContext, color);
 CGContextSetLineCap(drawingContext,kCGLineCapRound);
 CGContextMoveToPoint(drawingContext,    lastPt.x - (31.0 / self.transform.a),  lastPt.y - (31.0 / self.transform.a)  );
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(drawingContext, currPt.x - (31.0 / self.transform.a),  currPt.y - (31.0 / self.transform.a)  );
 CGContextStrokePath(drawingContext);
 } else {
 //                     CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(drawingContext, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
 //                     CGContextFillRect(drawingContext,    CGRectMake( currPt.x - (31.0 / self.transform.a) - 16.0 , currPt.y - (31.0 / self.transform.a) - 16.0 , 40.0 , 40.0) );
 CGContextClearRect(drawingContext, CGRectMake( currPt.x - (31.0 / self.transform.a) - 16.0 , currPt.y - (31.0 / self.transform.a) - 16.0 , 40.0 , 40.0) );
 }

 UIGraphicsPopContext();
 CGImageRelease(cgImage);
 NSLog(@"    %@   "  ,  rect);
 [image drawInRect: rect];

 lastPt = currPt;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found changing the call from

```
[self setNeedsDisplay]
```

to

```
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect]
```

change from 1fps  to  52fps  according to Instruments